# Mysql select multiple records

Tags: mysql, performance

I have 3 tables `a b c` a b and c all are related through an id `a.id = b.id = c.id`

My task is to select all rows from a b and c where `a.date` is older than 6 months and insert them into a new db for archiving.

Here is what I have so far:

```
insert into dbArchive.a select * from db.a where receivedDate < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH;`
```

This seems to select all entries from table a that are older than 6 months and insert them into the archive db table a.

What is the best and most efficient way to find all rows from tables b and c that have the same id and insert them to the archive db tables b and c?

I have over 1 million records that are older than 6 months so I am weary about performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing around for a while this seems to be the best approach I have found that actually works:

```
INSERT INTO archive.b SELECT * FROM db.b WHERE `id` IN( SELECT `id` FROM archive.a )
```

I am not sure if this is the most efficient method but it gets the job done

Comment: Yes. This works. I was bit over-thought. It needs to know the factors how, `SELECT`, `JOIN`, inner queries work to properly find the efficiency. Here, I think this is more efficient as no `JOIN` is used. If you have got time, you can test them both and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

After inserting into `dbArchive.a` as you have done here, you can run the following to insert into `dbArchive.b` and same way for `dbArchive.c`.

```
INSERT INTO dbArchive.b(id, etc..) 
  SELECT db.b.id, etc.. 
  FROM dbArchive.a INNER JOIN db.b ON dbArchive.a.id = db.b.id;
```

Comment: Ok... Can i use a `SELECT` vs `VALUES (....)` to simply copy everything vs specifying the columns? I always get confused when joining tables as well as inserts combined with selects.

Comment: Check edited answer. It had some mistakes. Yes you can if the columns matches the values. Here you can omit the column names in `INSERT INTO` if you pass values for all columns but you need to specify `SELECT` columns as values are available from both `dbArchive.a` and `db.b`.

Comment: I have been playing around with this a bit. It's not quite working but its close. I have the following: `SELECT rdo.qs_mailContent.id, rdo.qs_mailContent.bodyText, rdo.qs_mailContent.bodyHTML, rdo.qs_mailContent.headers FROM qs_mailArchive.qs_mail INNER JOIN rdo.qs_mailContent ON qs_mailArchive.qs_mail.id = rdo.qs_mailContent.id LIMIT 10` This returns results with the following IDs: `2 5 7 118....` If I change this statement to the following: `SELECT * FROM qs_mailArchive.qs_mail INNER JOIN rdo.qs_mailContent ON qs_mailArchive.qs_mail.id = rdo.qs_mailContent.id limit 10`....

Comment: I get the following IDs: `1, 2 3, 5, 7` this is the expected set of results. This gives me way too much data for the insert however. Any thoughts as to why this would change my results?